# FireBase removeValue in iOS not always persisting to database

Tags: ios, firebase

I am testing FireBase in my iOS app and it is pretty amazing so far but it seems if I use `[fb removeValue];` when I am not connected the change is not always reflected any where else.

Here is my code:

```
-(void) deleteFromFirebase {
    Firebase *fb =[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://repzio.firebaseio.com/orders/%@/%@",self.purchaseOrder.ManufacturerID, self.purchaseOrder.OrderGUID]];
    [fb removeValue];
}
```

Obviously this causes issues when the app need to remove data and have it persisted.  Has anyone else run into this issue?  Am I handling this wrong?

Comment: The value should get removed the next time you come online. However, if your app is killed before it comes back online, you may lose the change. Is this what you're seeing?

Comment: that could be the case, I'll investigate - do you know if there is a way to see the Firebase queue so I can save it for anything actions that were not able to process before my app gets killed?

Comment: Not currently, until we roll out disk persistence for iOS, you'll have to maintain your own queue of changes. You can do this by listening to the .info/connected endpoint which will notify you about changes in connectivity.

Answer (score 3):

I would use blocks!

```
[fb removeValueWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref) {
    if (!error) {
        // Save worked
    }
    else {
        // cache for later, or notify user that there was an error and they should try again.
    }
}];
```